# Weird string comparision when perforing ajax request in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, comparison

Have a weird problem in javascript. I am performing a check against the backend with Jquery to check if the mail is already existing in the database. The answer is either true or false.

The problem is that if the answer is true i get that the data variable contains "true", but the check:

```
data == "true"
```

fails anyway. The code seem somehow to evaluate "true" == "true" to false.

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data == "true") {
        emailAlreadyIsUsed = true;
    } else {
        emailAlreadyIsUsed = false;
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what this depend on?

I am new to develop in javascript, is there a good way to debug this? I have steped through this code in chrome checking the values of the variables.

Comment: Are you sure it's a string? If i evaluate `true == "true"` it returns `false`, if I evaluate `"true" == "true"` it returns `true`

Comment: What is the value of data exactly. You could try to cast the value of data to a real bool with `!!data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers.

What I in the end made to make this work is to change the dataType to "json". Then the variable **data** contains a boolean variable which I can normaly use.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's not a String, try `data == true` or `if(data){...` should work. How is it being set server side?

Comment: If I do "data == true" then it always evaluates to false even if data contains "true". if I do if(data) then it always evaluates to true. I have dataType set to "text" and I return the answer with php with following code: echo $isEmailExisting ? 'true' : 'false';

Comment: You're setting it as a string in php. Ignore first answer. Perhaps set it as `true` or `false` in your php then use the code in my original answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare string with other string you can do this in following way:

```
success: function(data) {
  emailAlreadyIsUsed = (data.indexOf('true') === 0);
}
```

But it is really strange that your code not working.

You can try strict comparison `===`.

```
success: function(data) {
   if (data === "true") {
       emailAlreadyIsUsed = true;
   } else {
       emailAlreadyIsUsed = false;
   }
}
```

Or try to compare two strings:

```
success: function(data) {
   if (String(data) === "true") {
       emailAlreadyIsUsed = true;
   } else {
       emailAlreadyIsUsed = false;
   }
}
```